# What is needed for a line to be an appropriate model for the data?

Tags: regression, r-squared

My answer key responds with a large $R^2$ and a residual plot with no pattern.

The residual plot with no pattern makes sense. 
However, is having a large $R^2$ necessary? A linear model can be appropriate, but weak, with a low $r$ value, thus it follows that a model can be appropriate, although weak with a low $R^2$ value.

Is the answer key padding with extra information?

(Note, I'm currently in AP Statistics, and I'm sorry if this is a really basic question! Thank you for taking your time, though!)

Comment: Some perspective on this is afforded in the thread at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/is-r2-useful-or-dangerous.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is.

Comment: The $R^2$ tells you nothing about the appropriateness of a linear model - even a very high $R^2$ doesn't say the model is linear and a ver low $R^2$ doesn't imply it isn't. It's perfectly possible for the "true" model to be linear but have an $R^2$ that's very close to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer key is incorrect. As Glen_b noted, a true linear relationship will not necessarily produce a high $R^2.$ Noisy data is one cause, for example. Correspondingly, a high $R^2$ does not guarantee linearity. Other models could still be better.